# Validation of two dropdown menus in PHP at once

Tags: php, html

Well, this is the first time I'm using StackOverflow to ask a question. And what's funny, this question is really trivial especially for me but I'm struggling!

Here's what I want to accomplish.

I'm writing a life-savior script for me and my buddy for a video game.

There are two dropdown menus with 5 options each (they are the same so I will just copy one menu)

```
<select name="start" class="form-control" id="start">
     <option value="tank" >Tank</option>
     <option value="armory" >Armory</option>
     <option value="dept" >Dept</option>
     <option value="comm" >Comm</option>
     <option value="infirmary" >Infirmary</option>
     <option value="depot" >Depot</option>
 </select>
```

I need to print a result after two of those are selected. So lets say, I select in the first menu Tank and in second Armory, I will get this as a result:

Tank -> 1

Infirmary -> 1

Dept Store -> 3

Command -> 1

Depot -> 2

The second selection doesn't need to be printed. Any way to handle it in PHP without js?

EDIT:

Ok, so you are asking for those integers, but those will be printed as a result of selection. I know which ones will be, it is a very complicated sequence to explain now so I will just enter answers for each selection. Don't bother with it. I will write in pseudo code what I want specifically.

```
If start == tank AND finish == armory

echo: 

   Tank -> 1

Infirmary -> 1

Dept Store -> 3

Command -> 1

Depot -> 2
```

those integers aren't predefined. I will just manually enter them for each sequence

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. I don't understand the whole `-> 1,2,3` stuff. Also, what do you mean by "print"? php is a server-side language and the only way to accomplish something like what you want is to submit the values of your dropdowns via a form and then print the result on a new page. Otherwise js would be required. Lastly, ... why no js?

Comment: I've skipped JS lessons :(

edited my post!

Comment: Alright, ignoring the integers. You don't say what you mean by print though. When should it be printed and how? What triggers it? Same page or different page?

Comment: print it after pressing "submit" button. same page or different page doesn't matter. it will be used once/two times daily. i want something familiar to gorodkrovi.com <- but I don't want to copy-paste it and want it for offline usage

Comment: The answer is: Yes, you can do this with php. Study some php and post a new question if you don't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, something like:

```
<?php
  if($_POST["start"] !== "" && $_POST["finish"] !== "" && $_POST["start"] !== $_POST["finish"]) {
    echo $_POST["start"];
  }
?>
```

This will print the value of the `start` dropdown if both dropdowns have something selected and don't have the same value selected. You can adjust this to fit your need.

To get this to submit you need to wrap your inputs within a `<form>` with `POST` that directs to the php file with the above code.